# Connecting Sqlite Database using Server,MapPath

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite

I am trying to connect to a SQLite Database using Server.MapPath in ashx file. It works well on localhost but when I run it from webserver it does not connect to the database. I wonder is it because of MapPath? Do I need to change to something else?

```
private static readonly string APP_PATH = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);
private static readonly string DB_PATH = Path.Combine(APP_PATH, "data");
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by using BaseDirectory:

```
private static readonly string DB_PATH = Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "data");
```